# APEX Interactive Grid column width

Tags: oracle-apex

I have an Interactive Grid with a lot of columns and APEX fits them all on the screen making them way to small to be useful.
How can I give them a default width and make them go off the screen with a scroll bar?

Changing the `Width` parameter for a column in the `Appearance` secion has no visual effect.

[image: screenshot]

I'm using APEX 5.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set the Minimum Column Width property for each column in the Interactive Grid's Actions menu:

[image]

[image]

Once done, you can use Actions>Report>Save to save these settings permanently.  The result (I just did this for 2 columns):

[image]

Comment: Could it be reproduced with custom function returning `config` object in `Attributes > Advanced > JavaScript`? Will these column configurations be applied for every user or just those who perform these steps?

Comment: @VELFR I don't know about the custom function idea.  The column config will be applied for every user if you save the report settings while logged in as a developer.

Comment: Thanks. But this seems to be not working in our case. We have changed the authorisation scheme, so users in an app are not the same users than in APEX. Are there any alternatives? Do you know where this config should be stored?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not the perfect solution.. but here is what I did:

- export the page,
- open it in notepad++
- look for `,p_width=>xx`

change xx with a number, save the file, import the page back.

it's way easier than using ACTION menu IMHO